# Remove all non a-zA-Z and non number strings form textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

The user should be enter only a-z, A-Z and 0-9. I show the user the UIKeyboardType.ASCIICapable keyboard layout.

How can i filter non a-z, A-Z and 0-9 from string after the user enter a string with keyboard.

How can i solve this issue? I'm using xcode 7 and swift 2.

Comment: Isn't it better user experience to filter **while** the user is entering a string?

Comment: @vadian yes of course. i'm in the learning process of swift and app development and not sure how can i filter this characters while user is entering characters

Comment: Look at Kumar's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with delegate method of `UITextField`

```
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let set: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().invertedSet

       if string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(set) != nil {
        return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: many thanks. is this "NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().invertedSet" the same with list of character do you list?

Comment: Yes , Edited the answer please check .

Comment: @KumarKL could you please unscramble invertedSet > invertedSet > != nil > return false. Actually it's simply `return string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(set) == nil` using the inverted alphanumeric set.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the inversion of your accepted set is present:

```
if yourtextfield.text!.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(letters.invertedSet) != nil {
    print("invalid")
}
```

letters should probably be `alphanumericCharacterSet()` if you want to include numbers as well.

Comment: this works. can i remove this invalid characters if != nil?

Comment: you are talking about print("invalid") ?